# Inserting a vector in a certain position in another vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to insert vector `b` in a certain position in a vector `a`. For Example

```
std::vector <int> vecta{ 10, 20, 30 ,40 , 50};
std::vector <int> vectb{ 1000, 2000, 3000 };
```

How can I have a result vector to be like  {10,20,1000,2000,3000,40,50}  ? 
I want to remove `30` and replace its with the vector.

Comment: A is the main vector and B  is the result of another computation process . I want to modify A with the values of B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to insert vector `b` in a certain position in a vector `a`

You may want to consider [`std::vector::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
vecta.insert(pos, vectb.begin(), vectb.end());
```

where `pos` above is an iterator pointing to the element (in `vecta`) *before* the content of `vectb` will be inserted. `pos` may be also the iterator returned by `end()`, which would mean *appending* the content of `vectb` to `vecta`.

---

> How can I have a result vector to be like {10,20,1000,2000,3000,40,50}

For that, you also need to remove the element `30` from `vecta`. You can do this with [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
auto main() -> int {
   std::vector <int> vecta{ 10, 20, 30, 40 , 50};
   /*                               ^
                                    |-- insert vectb here and replace the 30
   */

   std::vector <int> vectb{ 1000, 2000, 3000 };

   // what element to erase from vecta?
   auto pos = vecta.begin() + 2;

   // erase it
   pos = vecta.erase(pos);

   // insert vectb in vecta
   vecta.insert(pos, vectb.begin(), vectb.end());

   for (auto& e: vecta)
      std::cout << e << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

`std::vector::erase()` returns the iterator that follows the removed element. Since you want to erase `30` from `vecta` and then insert `vectb` at that position, you can simply pass the iterator `erase()` returns to `insert()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `erase` to erase an element at a certain iterator position and `insert` to insert elements before a certain iterator position. To step an iterator, use `std::next` and `std::prev`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vecta{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    std::vector<int> vectb{1000, 2000, 3000};

    // erase 30 from the vector
    vecta.erase(std::next(vecta.begin(), 2));

    // insert vectb before position 2
    vecta.insert(std::next(vecta.begin(), 2), vectb.begin(), vectb.end());

    for(int v : vecta) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
10 20 1000 2000 3000 40 50
```

An alternative that doesn't require `erase`. This is probably slightly faster:

```
#include <utility> // added for std::swap

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vecta{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    std::vector<int> vectb{1000, 2000, 3000};

    std::vector<int> result;

    // reserve space for the number of elements you know will be in the resulting vector
    result.reserve(vecta.size() - 1 + vectb.size());

    // append the 2 first elements from vecta
    result.insert(result.end(), vecta.begin(), std::next(vecta.begin(), 2));

    // append vectb
    result.insert(result.end(), vectb.begin(), vectb.end());

    // append the last two elements from vecta
    result.insert(result.end(), std::prev(vecta.end(), 2), vecta.end());

    // let vecta take over the data in result and vice-a-versa
    std::swap(result, vecta);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

[**Live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BE3Jo3rFJrXOT2dS)

```
vecta.erase(vecta.begin() + 2); //<-- erase 30 element
```

```
vecta.insert(vecta.begin() + 2, vectb.begin(), vectb.end());
```

`vecta.begin() + 2` being the point of insertion of `vectb` in `vecta` and `vectb.begin(), vectb.end()` the span of the elements of `vectb` you need to insert, In this case, all of them.